ZFS High utilization and await on a single disk
I have a TrueNAS system running with 4xSSD under a single raidz1 pool, an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220L V2 @ 2.30GHz and 8GB RAM
The underlying for this TrueNAS system is a Debian 12
Linux colossus 6.6.32-production+truenas #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul  8 16:11:58 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# zpool status colossus
  pool: colossus
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 4.69M in 00:00:01 with 0 errors on Wed Oct  2 08:08:14 2024
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    colossus    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb2    ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda2    ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc2    ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd2    ONLINE       0     0     0

I've noticed the system gets extremely slow under high disk reads or writes with high IOWAIT, in particular a single SSD disk with high utilization and high await
11:47:08          DEV       tps     rkB/s     wkB/s     dkB/s   areq-sz    aqu-sz     await     %util
11:47:09          sdc      4.00     92.00     44.00      0.00     34.00      4.97   1243.00    100.00
11:47:09          sdd      3.00     36.00     16.00      0.00     17.33      0.00      0.67      0.40
11:47:09          sdb      2.00      0.00     16.00      0.00      8.00      0.00      0.50      0.40
11:47:09          sda      3.00     40.00     16.00      0.00     18.67      0.00      0.67      0.40

11:47:09          DEV       tps     rkB/s     wkB/s     dkB/s   areq-sz    aqu-sz     await     %util
11:47:10          sdc      4.00     56.00     88.00      0.00     36.00      6.60   1649.50    100.00
11:47:10          sdd      4.00     24.00     24.00      0.00     12.00      0.00      0.50      0.40
11:47:10          sdb      4.00     12.00     24.00      0.00      9.00      0.01      1.50      0.40
11:47:10          sda      5.00     40.00     24.00      0.00     12.80      0.00      0.60      0.40

11:47:10          DEV       tps     rkB/s     wkB/s     dkB/s   areq-sz    aqu-sz     await     %util
11:47:11          sdc      2.00     36.00     88.00      0.00     62.00      2.96   1482.00    100.00
11:47:11          sdd      3.00     88.00     44.00      0.00     44.00      0.00      0.33      0.80
11:47:11          sdb      4.00    132.00     44.00      0.00     44.00      0.00      1.00      0.80
11:47:11          sda      4.00    120.00     44.00      0.00     41.00      0.00      0.25      0.80

I initially though it could be a problem with that particular disk, however when I offline that disk the high usage/await simply moves to another disk.
QUESTION: Are there any ZFS settings I should be using to avoid a single disk having much higher usage than others in a raidz1? Or perhaps my bottleneck is somewhere else (MEM or CPU not powerful enough for ZFS?)
